# Why can't I use make_pair to tie?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, c++03, std-pair

I'm trying to mimic the behavior of [`tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) pre C++11.

```
pair<int, int> test() {
    return make_pair(13, 42);
}

int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2;

    pair<int&, int&>(a, b) = test();

    cout << a << ' ' << b << endl;
}
```

[This works](http://ideone.com/LPHWSS) however if I use `make_pair` instead to the `pair` constructor `a` and `b` are not assigned.
Why does the `pair` constructor work but not `make_pair`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 20.2.2[lib.pairs]8 the standard states that `pair` uses "explicit types" while `make_pair`'s "types are deduced".

This is why the standard defines a constructor for `pair`:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
pair(const T1& x, const T2& y)
```

If you run your code on a [C++03 compiler](http://ideone.com/T3OuMS) you will get this error:

> non-static reference member `int& std::pair<int&, int&>::first`, can't use default assignment operator

The problem is that `pair` uses an [implicitly-declared copy assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Deleted_implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator) which is not defined if the `pair`:

> Has a non-static data member of a reference type

Whether defined by `make_pair` or the `pair` constructor, the template arguments will define both of the `pair`'s members as `int&` so the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator will not be defined. **So this cannot be accomplished with a `pair` in C++03.**

If using return parameter is undesirable, you can write your own implementation of [`tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
template <class T1, class T2>
struct tie{
    T1& first;
    T2& second;

    tie(T1& x, T2& y) : first(x), second(y) {}

    tie<T1, T2>& operator=(const pair<T1, T2>& rhs){
        first = rhs.first;
        second = rhs.second;

        return *this;
    }
};
```

This will allow assignment of a `pair`:

```
tie<int, int>(a, b) = test();
```

To get the exact C++11 behavior which doesn't require template arguments you'll need to define a function. If `tie` is nested in `namespace details` the function can be defined as:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
details::tie<T1, T2> tie(T1& x, T2& y) { 
    return details::tie<T1, T2>(x, y);
}
```

This will allow assignment of a `pair` just as in C++11:

```
tie(a, b) = test();
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/6TbUxM)

<sub>Note that this is still intolerant of using `int&` template arguments, so `details::tie<int&, int&>` and `tie<int&, int&>` will fail just as before.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can use `std::make_pair`. But you need to implement `reference_wrapper` class to imitate reference. Examplary (not very polished, but working as expected) c++03 approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct reference_wrapper {
   bool is_const;
   T* v;
   T const* cv;
   reference_wrapper(T& t): v(&t), is_const(false) { }
   reference_wrapper(T const& t): cv(&t), is_const(true) { }

   reference_wrapper &operator=(reference_wrapper const &rw) {
      if (rw.is_const) {
         *v = *rw.cv;
      } else {
         *v = *rw.v;
      }
   }
};

template <class T>
reference_wrapper<T> ref(T &t) {
   return reference_wrapper<T>(t);
}

pair<int, int> test() {
    return make_pair(13, 42);
}

int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2;

    //pair<int&, int&>(a, b) = test();  // works
    make_pair(ref(a), ref(b)) = test(); // now it does work

    std::cout << a << ' ' << b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer better than mine, but `std::ref` is only available since C++11

Comment: @krzaq I was going to say that! If you're using `ref` you're better off using `tie`.

Comment: @krzaq The edit now works on a C++03 system. I wrote [an alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39750232/2642059) while I was waiting on your edit. But I think we're both trying to do the same thing. +1 for another way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

`make_pair` produces a pair of values, not references. That means it would produce `pair<int, int>` in your example and you'd be assigning results of `test()` to a temporary variable¹.

You can mimic `tie` with the following:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
std::pair<T&, U&> tie_pair(T& l, U& r)
{
    return std::pair<T&, U&>(l, r);
}
```

http://ideone.com/muAcaG

¹​ this is an unfortunate side-effect of C++03 not having ref-qualifiers. In C++≥11 you can delete `operator=` for rvalue `this` (in non-std classes) and make such cases a compiler error rather than silent surprising behaviour.

Comment: I've validated what you're saying by trying to do this. `pair<int&, int&> foo = make_pair<int&, int&>(a, b)` and it errors: "conversion from `std::pair<int, int>` to non-scalar type `std::pair<int&, int&>` requested" So clearly you are correct, but could you elaborate a little more on why this is? Why can I even pass those as template-arguments if `make_pair` is just going to strip the reference type?

Comment: You're not supposed to provide template parameters to `make_pair`. That you can is just an (unfortunate in this case) effect of the language semantics. As far as the *why* goes - it's because it was designed to make a standalone value, not a reference. I'm not sure about a specific implementation and I don't have C++ 2003 standard handy to give a better explanation